# Including .asp that contains JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have two files A.asp and B.asp . The B.asp contains long javascript function that i want to use in A.asp. To include it, i used:

```
<!--#include file="lib/B/B.asp"-->
```

...in the head of A.asp I added:

```
<script>
```

function use(){

```
try{
    test = new FPDF();
}catch(err){
    document.write(err);
}
```

}

new FPDF() is an object reference to function FPDF() in B.asp file that looks like this:

```
<script>
function FPDF(){
var x;
this.x = function x(){
...
}

}
</script>
```

I get an error message: "ReferenceError: FPDF is not defined"... How can i properly do this?
What i want to do is to call the function in FPDF() like this:

```
<script>
```

function use(){

```
try{
    test = new FPDF();
            test.x();               //!!!!
}catch(err){
    document.write(err);
}
```

}

Comment: Suggest you view source, save and try and debug that.  The include file directive basically just tells the server to copy and paste the contents of the include file into the html output

Comment: I don't understand what is your advice with this comment...

Comment: Forget my comment above, I've had a look at your sourceforge download.  They contain server side javascript, so you'll need server side code to call your function.  Either you need to add runat="server" to your script tags or you need to define the page language as Jaascript and wrap your code inside <% %>

Comment: If I put the script tags to runat="server", then when i press the button onclick can't find the function use().. It says it's not defined..

Answer (score 0):

Create an external javascript file  like (myscript.js) and keep all your javascript code there.In a.asp reference that javascript file similary in b.asp reference the same javascript file.

Example --- in a.asp

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

 <script src="/myscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Simiraly in b.asp-----

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

 <script src="/myscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, but this B.asp was specially created to use in ASP classic. If I create external javascript file, it could be used in any language. Check it out here: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/aspdf/
...this is the file I'm working with. I mean, i could do that but I don't see the point why was it created for asp, not generally for javascript??

Answer (score 0):

The "runat=server" instruction does precisely that, it tells the server to execute the code rather than serve it as is for the web browser to interpret.  To give you a very simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Jscript" runat="server">
  var helloworld = "Hello World";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%= helloworld %>
</body>
</html>
```

When this page is requested the server will send the following to the browser

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

So the reason your onclick button doesn't work is that there's no JS on the page which it can see.  If you want to send variables to a server side function then you'll need to post them to the page in a form and then use Request.Form to retrieve them.

I hope this helps